# JQuery ui slider doesn't allow posting two diff. slider values on same FORM?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using two different sliders on same function (also tried different functions as well)
(See my code below) when form posts, i get only one slider value, How to remove conflict?

```
$(function() {
        var t_select = $( "#taste_val1" );
        var slider = $( "<div id='type_slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( t_select ).slider({
            min: 1,
            max: 2,
            range: "max",
            value: t_select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                t_select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
            }
        });
        $( "#taste_val1" ).change(function() {
            type_slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
        });

        var d_select = $( "#taste_val2" );
        var slider = $( "<div id='dist_slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( d_select ).slider({
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
            range: "min",
            value: d_select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                d_select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
            }
        });
        $( "#taste_val2" ).change(function() {
            dist_slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
        });
    });

FORM CODE 1st Selector:
 <td width="65%" valign="top"> 
    <form id="reservation">
    <select name="taste_val1" id="taste_val1" style="display:none;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form></td>

2nd SELECTOR:
   <td width="65%" valign="top"> 
    <form id="search">
        <select name="taste_val2" id="taste_val2" style="display:none;">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    </td>
```

Please, Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm reading this all wrong, but shouldn't

```
var slider = $( "<div id='type_slider'></div>" )
```

be

```
var type_slider = $( "<div id='type_slider'></div>" )
```

(and similary for the dist_slider).

Comment: I changed the var names but still no luck, Actually it only posts first selector value, don't know why :S